# How to create exact JSON format to POST method in c# code?

Tags: c#, json, post, httprequest

Web Service required this format:

```
{
   "Data":"{\"Name\":\"HelloWorld\",\"BirthDate\":\"2020-03-03\",\"BirthPlace\":\"Nowhere\"}"
}
```

I required above format to post to web service but my code below doesn't fulfil the format. Please help. I've been using below code to post

```
 var Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
 {
    Data = new
    {
      Name= "HelloWorld",
      BirthDate = "2020-03-03",
      BirthPlace= "Nowhere"
    }
 });
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
 {
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiUrl, Data);
 }
```

Comment: Surely you dont need to post the escape on the quotes? (\")

Comment: Print the string you get and compare it to your required string. You'll find that you get `{"Data":{"Name":"HelloWorld","BirthDate":"2020-03-03","BirthPlace":"Nowhere"}}`

Comment: Unrelated: `using (var client = new HttpClient())` is just for the example, right? You shouldn't use it that way in production code.

Comment: If The data property must really be a string with the serialisation of the inner object you can simply serilise it twice.   `var Data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
  new
  {
   Data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
   {
    Name = "HelloWorld",
    BirthDate = "2020-03-03", 
    BirthPlace = "Nowhere"
   })
  });`

Comment: @xdtTransform You should write that up as answer. Seems reasonable to me and it is a different approach from my answer. In fact, I find it a little bit better.

Comment: Thank you so much @xdtTransform, this really helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If data should contains a string serialization of the real object. You can simply serialize the inner object using the string result as value on your second serialization.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static string WrapAndSerialize(object value){
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { Data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value) });  
}
```

Using it like:

```
var myObject= 
  new
  {
     Name = "HelloWorld",
     BirthDate = "2020-03-03", 
     BirthPlace = "Nowhere",
  };

var Data= WrapAndSerialize(myObject);
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(apiUrl, Data);
}
```

[LiveDemo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4UNg04)

Answer (score 1):

To get the required format do:

```
string name = "HelloWorld";
string birthdate = "2020-03-03";
string birthplace= "Nowhere";
var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    Data = $"\"Name\"=\"{name}\",\"BirthDate\"=\"{birthdate}\",\"BirthPlace\"=\"{birthplace}\""
});
```

See it in action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/UBXDtd

The format states that `Data` shall contain a `string`. Your code serializes an object with properties, which results in:

```
{"Data":{"Name":"HelloWorld","BirthDate":"2020-03-03","BirthPlace":"Nowhere"}}
```

EDIT: While this works, I would recommend @xdtTransform's answer over this. Leaving this here, in case his solution is for some reason not applicable.